# How to reduce the canvas size of an SVG icon?

Tags: svg, icons

I need some help with SVG icons. I have an issue with a set of payment icons that I found online. I don't know how to explain it but basically all of their canvases takes more space than they should.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/p4JKZJK

I would like the canvases of the icons to be as big as the icons themselves. As you can see in the screenshot, now the icons take up more space than they should.

Is it possible to fix this? Can something be edited in the code of the payment icons to reduce the size of their canvases?

The code of the Diners Club payment icon:

```html
<svg width="270" height="231" viewBox="0 0 270 231" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<rect x="40.75" y="40.75" width="185.432" height="126.682" rx="15.25" fill="white" stroke="#D9D9D9" stroke-width="1.5"/>
</g>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M125.743 144.148H139.528C161.045 144.148 178.191 126.977 178.864 105.765V105.429C178.527 83.8805 161.045 66.3727 139.528 66.7094H124.062C103.554 67.3827 87.416 84.8906 88.0884 105.765C88.0884 126.64 104.899 143.811 125.743 144.148ZM94.8125 105.428C94.8125 87.9207 109.269 73.4431 126.752 73.4431C144.235 73.4431 158.691 87.9207 158.691 105.428C158.691 122.936 144.235 137.414 126.752 137.414C109.269 137.414 94.8125 122.936 94.8125 105.428ZM131.795 126.977V84.2171C143.562 87.2473 150.959 99.0314 147.933 110.816C145.916 118.896 139.864 124.956 131.795 126.977ZM105.907 100.041C102.881 111.826 109.942 123.946 121.709 126.977V84.2171C113.976 86.2372 107.924 92.2976 105.907 100.041Z" fill="#1B79BE"/>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="270" height="231" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: you may try to use a different viewBox (`<svg width="270" viewBox="40 40 187 128"`) and no height. Also the filter is not doing anything

Comment: Hi @enxaneta. Thanks for your reply. I implemented the change you suggested and it helped. But what do you mean by "the filter is not doing anything"?

Comment: delete the `filter="url(#filter0_d)"` and you'll see. The filter is using stdDeviation="0" and that matrix for feColorMatrix doesn't help either

Comment: Oh ok, thank for telling me. I deleted `filter="url(#filter0_d)"` and `type="matrix"` in all of the icons. The icons didn't change but there's less code taking up unnecessary space.